# How to create an arc with different colors in SVG with html?

Tags: html, svg

I need to create an svg image like this
[image]

```html
<svg width="600" height="400">
    <path d="M100,200 Q250,100 400,200" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="25px" />
</svg>
```

I tried the above code but I don't know how to specify the color gradients.

Comment: It's likely several arcs placed end to end.

Comment: and then positioned with ``pathLength`` and ``stroke-dasharray`` and ``stroke-dashoffset``

Answer (score 3):

`<circle>` can be used in combination with `stroke-dasharray`, `stroke-dashoffset` and `pathLength`.

I chose a path length of 200 to make the upper part of the arc 100 % and the negative numbers in dashoffset are then the startingpoint and the fist number in dasharray are the length of the lines. I rotate the entire thing to make it start at 9 o'clock.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 60" width="400">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/>
  <g transform="rotate(180 50 50)" fill="none" stroke-width="5">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="yellow"
      stroke-dashoffset="-90" stroke-dasharray="10 200" pathLength="200" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="blue"
      stroke-dashoffset="-65" stroke-dasharray="25 200" pathLength="200" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="green"
      stroke-dashoffset="-40" stroke-dasharray="25 200" pathLength="200" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" stroke="red"
      stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="40 200" pathLength="200" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

- And then make it a Standard Web Component `<svg-arcs>` supported in all Browsers
- to make it (your own) semantic HTML
- use an `UnknownHTMLElement <segment>`
- that get replaced by `<circle>`

```js
customElements.define("svg-arcs", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout(() => { // make sure innerHTML <segments> are parsed as DOM
      let offset = -90;
      let width = this.getAttribute("width") || 8;
      let segments = [...this.querySelectorAll("segment")]; 
      let circles = segments.map((s,idx)=>{
             let size = Number(s.getAttribute("size"));
             let stroke = s.getAttribute("stroke");
             if (idx) offset += size;
             return  `<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="${50-width}"
                              stroke="${stroke}"
                              stroke-dashoffset="${offset}" 
                              stroke-dasharray="${size} 200" 
                              pathLength="200"/>`;
             }).join(""); 
      this.innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
        <g transform="rotate(180 50 50)" fill="none" 
           stroke-width="${width}">${circles}</g></svg>`;
    });
  }
})
```

```css
svg-arcs{
  width:300px;
  background:beige;
}
body{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<svg-arcs>
  <segment size="10" stroke="yellow" />
  <segment size="25" stroke="green" />
  <segment size="25" stroke="blue" />
  <segment size="40" stroke="red" />
</svg-arcs>

<svg-arcs width="20">
  <segment size="10" stroke="yellow" />
  <segment size="25" stroke="green" />
  <segment size="25" stroke="blue" />
  <segment size="40" stroke="red" />
</svg-arcs>
```

Comment: The `<segment>` is unknown as you write. You can replace them with range input elements so that they render the correct values if web components are not supported -- and they would have a label element that writes out the color.

Comment: Great suggestion

Comment: Semantic markup -> Web components next level

Comment: ... current level: https://pie-meister.github.io/