# D3.js join function breaks the donut chart SVG structure

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, gauge, donut-chart

I'm trying to implement something like "Gauge graph" (or donut chart) using D3.js for dataset that represents binding between statuses of network devices and quantity of devices having such status:

```
{
  "Operational": 1,
  "Warning": 4,
  "Offline": 2,
  ...
}
```

*Dataset may change over time: some other statuses can be added, some of the statuses can be removed, and/or quantity numbers can be also changed.*

I've implemented the logic to do that, but **sometimes on some particular datasets it breaks the structure of the root SVG element**.

### Steps to reproduce

To reproduce it open [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkv6ayus/47/): as you see, everything works fine: each `<path>` is under their parent `<g>`.

```
<svg width="400" height="200" viewBox="-200,-150,400,200" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;">
  <g>
    <path d="M-98.99819570566463,-0.5977014496607642A99,99,0,0,1,-80.2110753965349,-58.02743647389048L-54.39727983232389,-39.11439564717636A67,67,0,0,0,-66.99733392439637,-0.5977014496607781Z" fill="green"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="M-79.50457242815314,-58.991719444482634A99,99,0,0,1,-0.10270506233973228,-98.9999467255926L-0.2627087045622808,-66.99948495426325A67,67,0,0,0,-53.69077686394212,-40.078678617768546Z" fill="lightblue"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="M1.0926828944767046,-98.99396973600017A99,99,0,0,1,98.99819570566463,-0.5977014496607955L66.99733392439637,-0.5977014496607884A67,67,0,0,0,0.9326792522541477,-66.99350796467084Z" fill="red"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[Screenshot: JSFiddle - correct example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FguKp.jpg)

But when I change the dataset by clicking on "Use 2<sup>nd</sup> dataset" button, I see that 2 of the `<path>`s are under the same `<g>`, and one of the `<g>`s is empty:

```
<svg width="400" height="200" viewBox="-200,-150,400,200" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;">
  <g>
    <path d="M-98.99819570566463,-0.5977014496607642A99,99,0,0,1,-70.25076521837927,-69.75550147645815L-47.67937956857289,-47.07097581265926A67,67,0,0,0,-66.99733392439637,-0.5977014496607781Z" fill="lightblue"></path>
    <path d="M-69.4033771719701,-70.59866313978799A99,99,0,0,1,90.99166365362825,-39.006629507623266L61.5038381189291,-26.575889385692513A67,67,0,0,0,-46.83199152216371,-47.914137475989136Z" fill="green"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="M91.45601811020627,-37.905101918153754A99,99,0,0,1,98.99819570566463,-0.5977014496607516L66.99733392439637,-0.5977014496607587A67,67,0,0,0,61.9681925755071,-25.474361796223004Z" fill="red"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[Screenshot: JSFiddle - broken layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxAvM.jpg)

It still looks fine, but this incorrect structure breaks the logic when data changes again.

### Question

My question is: what I'm doing wrong? I suppose that the problem is in the [data join key function](https://observablehq.com/@dnarvaez27/understanding-enter-exit-merge-key-function#cell-470), but I cannot understand the root cause.

### Playground

See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkv6ayus/47/).

Comment: You can create one without D3 in a few lines of JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71748808/how-to-create-an-arc-with-different-colors-in-svg-with-html/71755063#71755063

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman yes, thank you for your suggestion, that's still an option, but I plan to use D3.js in some other components of my app, not only to draw this gauge-like diagram, hence it makes sense for me to use the same tool everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**New answer:**

My original answer, as you pointed out, just masked the root cause.  The real issue here is *missing values* -  meaning, you have two datasets that'll produce data-binding with missing keys based on your key function.  This causes `d3` to "miscalculate" the enter vs update selections.

Here's a new runnable snippet with comments to explain what I changed:

```html
<html>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
  <figure id="gauge_graph"></figure>
  <button onclick="useFirstDataset()">Use 1<sup>st</sup> dataset</button>
  <button onclick="useSecondDataset()">Use 2<sup>nd</sup> dataset</button>

  <script>
/**
 * Datasets
 */
const FIRST_DATASET = {
  Operational: 2,
  Unknown: 3,
  Error: 5
};
const SECOND_DATASET = {
  Unknown: 2,
  Operational: 5,
  Error: 1,
};

/**
 * Constants
 */
const GAUGE_WIDTH_PX = 400;
const GAUGE_HEIGHT_PX = 200;
const GAUGE_ARC_RADIUS_PX = Math.min(GAUGE_WIDTH_PX, GAUGE_HEIGHT_PX) / 2;
const COLORS = {
  Operational: 'green',
  Error: 'red',
  Warning: 'orange',
  Offline: 'grey',
  Unknown: 'lightblue',
};

/**
 * Creating svg element
 */
d3.select('figure#gauge_graph')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', GAUGE_WIDTH_PX)
  .attr('height', GAUGE_HEIGHT_PX)
  .attr('viewBox', [
    -GAUGE_WIDTH_PX / 2,
    -GAUGE_HEIGHT_PX / 2 - GAUGE_ARC_RADIUS_PX / 2,
    GAUGE_WIDTH_PX,
    GAUGE_HEIGHT_PX,
  ])
  .attr(
    'style',
    'display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;'
  );

/**
 * Defining elements: d3.pie, that distributes values over the circle, and d3.arc, that actually draws the line
 */
const pie = d3
  .pie()
  .startAngle(-Math.PI / 2)
  .endAngle(Math.PI / 2)
  .padAngle(1 / GAUGE_ARC_RADIUS_PX)
  .sort(null)
  .value(d => d.value); //<-- simplified value func based on new data structure

const arc = d3
  .arc()
  .innerRadius(GAUGE_ARC_RADIUS_PX * 0.67)
  .outerRadius(GAUGE_ARC_RADIUS_PX - 1);

/**
 * Function that sets/updates data
 */
function updateGaugeData(dataset) {

  // normalize the data on each call
  // this will produce the kind of data d3 likes - an array of objects
  // without potential missing values
  const normData = pie(
    Object.keys(COLORS).map(key => ({key: key, value: dataset[key] || 0}))
  );

  d3
    .select('figure#gauge_graph svg')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(normData, d => d.data.key) //<-- simplified key func based on new data structure
    .join(
      function(enter) {
        return enter
          .append('g')
          .append('path')
          .attr('d', arc)
          .attr('fill', d => COLORS[d.data.key]); //<-- simplified color selection
      },
      function(update) {
        return update
          .select('path')
          .attr('d', arc);
      },
      function(exit) {
        return exit.remove()
      }
    );
}

updateGaugeData(FIRST_DATASET);

/**
 * Click handlers
 */
function useFirstDataset() {
  updateGaugeData(FIRST_DATASET);
}

function useSecondDataset() {
  updateGaugeData(SECOND_DATASET);
}

  </script>
</html>
```

**Old sub-par answer:**

You need to hold a reference to you selection instead of re-selecting it each time you call your update function:

```
const slices = d3
  .select('figure#gauge_graph svg')
  .selectAll('g');

function updateGaugeData(dataset) {

  slices
    .data(
      pie(Object.entries(dataset)),
      function(datum) {
        return datum.data[0]; // <-- using status name (e. g. "Operational", "Warning") as a key
      }
    )
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution, but seems like it produces new '<g>'s with '<path>'s inside every time the dataset changes.  Yeah, it looks fine, but the internal SVG's structure is getting bloated...

Comment: Well, I'm embarrassed.   That's what I get for rushing an answer before getting to root cause.  See updated answer.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot, but may I ask you a couple of questions about your updated solution?
First - you said that I'm missing keys in my implementation, could you please clarify where exactly it happens? Every time dataset changes I create 2-dimensional array of key-value pairs and then using it to choose the key just by getting "status" value by index. I expect, for example, that if "Offline" sector isn't displayed, but dataset has it and "Offline" is a key, then D3 should add it to the gauge, right?

Comment: Second - I noticed that there are some paths with zero widths inside SVG added for "statuses" those are not in dataset. Not a problem, I guess I can add a simple filter function before, but it also increases the total algorithm time/space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with modifying the same svg each time. I'm not sure exactly why your error is happening, but it seems like the pieces of the pie reach a point where they no longer adjust between the two dataset values. I was able to fix the issue by resetting the svg each time the button is clicked. The code below removes the old svg and creates a new one.

```
function useFirstDataset() {
  d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
  updateGaugeData(FIRST_DATASET);
}

function useSecondDataset() {
  d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
  updateGaugeData(SECOND_DATASET);
}
```

Comment: thanks, that definitely makes sense, I also thought about this approach, but I assumed that it's not optimal: seems like removing everything and then creating all the sectors again consumes more resources than modifying existing ones. It's not so critical on such small datasets like I have, but it may affect performance if I'll have more data, or the visualisation structure will be more complex. Apart from that I guess it won't be possible to use smooth transitions here, because every time the gauge will be created from scratch.